# How to do a "findByCategory" in a ManyToMany products schema in Spring JPA Repository class?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data, many-to-many

*I am new to Java Spring Frameworks and I know this title sounds too specific, but the answer to this question is useful for any similar many-to-many schemas. I searched a lot for this answer and found none. **Please:** read full body before downvote or relate to other questions.*

I have the entities `Product` and `Category` and they are `many-to-many` related and generated at `run-time`.

In my `REST` application I have three important `end-points` that uses that schema:

1. `/category` to list all categories as a menu;
2. `/products?description=` to list products filtered by terms in description field;
3. `/category/{id}/products` to list products that are in this category.

I have difficult with this last one, as I was told that I should use the `@Query` *annotation* to make a `join` and a `where` to get the job done. But I believe Spring JPA engineers could not leave this such common task outside the *JPA Way*.

The second end-point has this method in its **repository**:

```
public Page<Produto> findByDescriptionIgnoreCaseContainingOrderByDescriptionAsc(String description, Pageable pageOptions);
```

The last end-point I was told it should be like:

```
@Query("select * from products p left join p.category c where c = ?1")
public List<Produto> findByOrderByDescriptionAsc(Lond idCategory)
```

---

**Can I** perform this search as `listByCategory(a way to get only one category)` **without** having to use the `@Query` annotation? If Yes, How?

Comment: what did you mean *a way to get only one category* can it be the First maybe?

Comment: I meant that a product is in as many categories as the user puts it. So I need the repository to find the products that are in that category **id** passed by in the URL /category/id/products.

Comment: So instead of using `@Query` on `findByOrderByDescriptionAsc` all you want to do is use a query method like `findByDescriptionIgnoreCaseContainingOrderByDescriptionAsc`?

Comment: You can also try `public List<Produto> findByCategoryId(Lond id)` or `public List<Produto> findByCategory(Category category)`

Comment: @AbdullahKhan your first comment references the second end-point, which is fine. My problem is with the 3rd and last end-point findByCategory. I will try your second comment and see if it works.

Comment: @AbdullahKhan the `findByCategoriesId` from your second comment is correct!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you want to get all product bu categoryId

```
List<Product> findByCategoriesIdOrderByDescriptionAsc(long categoryId)
```

OR
if you want to get only one record

```
Product findFirstByCategoriesIdOrderByDescriptionAsc(long categoryId)
```

Comment: Thank you Tipu, your answer was accepted by the Spring Repository Engine.

Comment: There was a problem with that approach: the resulted query is not using `join` but just adding all three tables. Very inneficient.

Comment: could you please post the entity and select query from log. in my case it's adding join